# How do I invoke a factory constructor with angular.mocks.inject?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

Consider this code:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_User_) {
    user = _User_;
}));
```

And this module/service:

```
angular.module('app.userModule', [])
.factory('User', function() {
    function User(data) {
        data.forEach(function (attr) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(attr))
                this[attr] = data[attr];
        })
    };

    User.prototype.getSomeAttr() { return this.attr; }

    return User;
};
```

How on earth can I pass 'data' into the User function constructor, using inject?

Edit: my example is derived from code here: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2014/07/angularjs-data-models-http-vs-resource-vs-restangular/

Comment: Your factory doesn't return anything. Could you please post real code? What is `Visit`?

Comment: Updated, thanks, and apologies for the discontinuity

Comment: Does that work with inject([...])? Can you show me an example? I'm super new to angularjs. Not sure how the  _ whatever _ syntax works with the inject() function and the documentation didn't seem to make it clear

Comment: Oh god, wait, are you saying that I can just create a new instance of User in the beforeEach block without needing any injection? Oh man

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that your factory returns a constructor function. This constructor function is injected by angular and assigned to `user`in your test. So, now that you have a reference to it, you just need to call it: `new user(data)`.

Comment: In my example above, what does the variable user contain after assignment? Do I just modify that to "user = new User(["hi"]);?

Comment: `user` contains a reference the the function `User` returned by your factory

Comment: Which is useless to me unless I can instantiate it with a constuctor parameter. How do I call "new user(data)" instead of getting something automatically through _ User _

Comment: Since user is the constructor function, call it: new user(data). Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you show me what the final output should look like?

Comment: Would it be: `beforeEach(inject(function (_User_) {
    user = new User(data); 
}));`? What the heck is the point of `_User_` notation?

Comment: This isn't working either: `beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            User = $injector.get('User');
            userInst = new User({name: 'one'});
        }));`